# SQL Data into a Grid / Table

Tags: php, sql, datagrid, tabular

I was wondering what would be the easiest way to show rows of data into a 4x4 grid / table. I have looked around for quite awhile now and I can't seem to find a solution / understand how to do it.

Heres the code that I am using to extract the data from the SQL database.

```
<?php
require('json.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("timetable") or die("No such database");
$sql = sprintf("
SELECT *
 FROM `event`
  WHERE `module` = 'SET08101'");

$result = mysql_query($sql)
 or die(mysql_error());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   print "<div>$row[id] $row[module] $row[day] $row[start]</div>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Use the Power, Luke... Use <table><tr><td> for grid

Comment: @Sergey I try to implement a table using those tags but I always seem to get a error with coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
<?php
require('json.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("timetable") or die("No such database");
$sql = sprintf("
SELECT *
 FROM `event`
  WHERE `module` = 'SET08101'");

$result = mysql_query($sql)
 or die(mysql_error());
 ?>
 <table>
 <?php
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   ?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row["id"];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["module"];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["day"];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["start"];?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php
  }
 ?>
 </table>
 <?php
?>
```

Comment: This error occurs for each of them "Notice: Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' in C:\wamp\www\ModuleInfo.php on line 42" for when I replace the code with that.

Comment: change $row[id] to $row['id'] and so on... (this is not an error but a notice)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require('json.php');

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("timetable") or die("No such database");


$sql = sprintf("SELECT *
                FROM `event`
                WHERE `module` = '%s'", 'SET08101');

echo "<table>";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   echo "<tr>
             <td>{$row['id']}</td>
             <td>{$row['module']}</td>
             <td>{$row['day']}</td>
             <td>{$row['start']}</td>
         </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```